# Name of file stuck in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

The weirdest thing is happening in Xcode.  I had a View Controller file, called SettingsViewController.  From SettingsViewController, I am trying to push GameViewController.  When I was making this file, I mistakenly named it ViewViewController instead of GameViewController (it was late :D).  I set the class of the files' respective views in the identity tab in the storyboard file.  Later, I tried to change the name of the file ViewViewController to GameViewController by right-clicking on it in the left column and clicking rename.  I went into the storyboard file, and changed the class of the game view.  Now, I can import the GameViewController file into the SettingsViewController file by saying

```
#import GameViewController.h
```

But the following line gives an error:

```
GameViewController *gvc = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
```

The error says `unknown type name GameViewController: Did you mean ViewViewController?`

Am I missing a change that needs to be made?  All I did was change the name of the file and change the class in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was about to post this question, I realized the answer.  I had to go into GameViewController.h and change the line

```
@interface ViewViewController : UIViewController
```

to

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
```

Then, in GameViewController.m, I had to change:

```
@interface ViewViewController ()
```

to

```
@interface GameViewController ()
```

and change

```
@implementation ViewViewController
```

to

```
@implementation GameViewController
```